# SKVideoNode not displaying video

Tags: ios, video, sprite-kit

I am attempting to display a video using Sprite Kit and SKVideoNode on iOS 7.1. Apple's documentation makes this seem pretty straight forward. An example taken from the Sprite Kit Programming Guide:

```
SKVideoNode *sample = [SKVideoNode videoNodeWithVideoFileNamed:@"sample.m4v"];
sample.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
[self addChild: sample];
[sample play];
```

I am trying the same code and seeing no video. The SKVideoNode is indeed in the node hierarchy. I've also tried multiple videos, all are H.264 AAC.

I found someone with a similar issue [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10644). They seemed to solve it by instantiating an AVPlayer. That doesn't display video for me either. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things first:

1. You have to add the Foundation.framework to your project.
2. Make sure you have added the video file to your project.
3. Make sure your video file is one of these formats: .mov .mp4 .m4v .3gp .3gpp

Try out the sample code I have below:

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation MyScene
{
     AVPlayer *_player;
     SKVideoNode *_videoNode;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        [self setupMovie];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setupMovie
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"loop" ofType:@"mov"]];
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: fileURL];

    _videoNode = [[SKVideoNode alloc] initWithAVPlayer:_player];
    _videoNode.size = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
    _videoNode.position = CGPointMake(150, 150);

    [self addChild:_videoNode];

    _player.volume = 1.0;
    [_videoNode play];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however I have tried that solution and I still am unsuccessful. I can confirm I have added the framework. On another note, what is the benefit of using the above method over using the videoNodeWithVideoFileNamed: class method of SKVideoNode?

Comment: Using AVPlayer gives you more control and doesn't suffer from the current app to background issues. Have you replaced the "loop" with the name of your video file? Have your replaced the "mov" with the extension of your video file? Did you add the video file to your project? If it still does not work, then create a new SpriteKit project and copy JUST the code I have, follow the previous instructions and see if it works. To paraphrase Sherlock Holmes: “Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be your bug.”

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification. I hadn't thought about the background issues. Anyways, you got me to working. I'm embarrassed to say it was my fault. I shouldn't have assumed my subclass of SKScene didn't have any issues. A silly mistake I'll try not to make again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hartix, what was the issue you fixed? That could help others debug their issues too. Perhaps you're not the only one with issues! ;-P

Comment: Addressed my issue.  It seems, unlike SKSpriteNode, SKVideoNode does not automatically determine "size".  After manually setting the size, the video appeared as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had just solved it by converting the video file's format with Prism, MPEG4 video encoder. Hope it helps.

Comment: For some reason the .mov file would not play unless on the simulator. Changing the video format to mp4 "solved" the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is asked around 20 months ago, but never the less I thought I should share my learnings as well (it could be helpful to programmers who are working on `SKVideoNode` and facing the same issue, also there case is same as mine and mentioned below), related to `SKVideoNode`, video view display related issues.

I was recently exploring `Sprite Kit` where I found `SKVideoNode` to play video files on a `SKScene`. I created a `GameScene` inherited from `SKScene` and added an instance  of `UIImageView` as `backgroundImage` on scenes `skview` (`[self.scene.view addSubview:aView]`) and next I created a `SKVideNode's` instance along with other `UIKit` subviews and `SKNode` childs added to the `scene.view` and `scene` respectively.

I configured the code for `SKVideNode's` as is mentioned in its documents of class refrence, I build and run the application to see video playing. But apart from video everything appeared on the screen, also when I increase the volume of the device, I was able to hear the sound(audio) of the video file.

Since I was able to hear audio so I thought I am missing some configuration or their is some issue due to which video view is not visible.

I tried some permutations and combination to use `AVPlayer`, different file formats but still the same behavior after this I started digging the views `layering` and `z index` concept to see if the video is not behind the background image or any other view, still same behavior.

Finally, what I did I removed every `child` and `subviews` (including background image) from the screen and tried to just play video, and this time the video view was visible on screen.

**In short what I concluded with above behaviors is that, "if using `Sprite Kit's` `SKVideoNode` want to play videos than we should play them in `SKScene` instances, and not on above any `UIKit` views, as the instance of `SKVideoNode` is not visible if we are trying to add it at position where there is a `UIKit` view already present".**

Well, as far as `SpriteKit` is concerned, it has `SKView` and `SKScene` inside a scene which allows a programmer to use both `SpriteKit` and `UIKit` elements in there games, but these types of issues could lead to a compromise in selecting the type of visual elements we want to use.

Answer (score -1):

You should either add the video file to your bundle and load it through your bundle, or deactivate sandboxing.